# How to modify the \sectiontitle command?

Tags: sectioning, unnumbered-sections

I am writing my PhD thesis and the pages have their headings set with `\chaptertitle` and `\sectiontitle`. However, I have included a special chapter on which I don’t want to include any numbering so I am using `\section*{}` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{}` commands but my problem is that the headings in the pages keep the last numbered section.

Does anybody know how to manually redefine the command `\sectiontitle`?

If it is of help I have found this topic but I do not get any difference. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238993/latex-get-the-name-of-an-unnumbered-subsection

Thank you in advance to everybody.

Comment: What page style do you use?  Have you looked at `\sectionmark`?

Comment: Thank You for your answer! I am using my institution latex format which uses `\newpagestye` and `\sethead`, so switching to another style seems a lot of work, but if I don't get to solve this issue you have pointed me to a great alternative!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solve the issue by myself, and I think it is fair to share what I learned. 
I didn’t get to change the value of `\sectiontitle` but I did the following work around which is a valid solution for me. 
I created a new variable which would take the value of the section title, and I also created a Boolean variable that would tell the header which `\sectiontitle` to use, so the solution has this form:

```
\newcommand{\sectiontitleA}{ }  % define the new section title command and leave it at blank
\newif\ifsectiontitleA          % Boolean variable
\sectiontitleAfalse             % Initialized to zero. 
\makeatletter                   % I don’t know why I do it this way but I think it is correct
\newenvironment{myseccc}[1]{    % I define the new enviroment
\renewcommand{\sectiontitleA}{#1}   % Modify the section title
\section*{#1}                   % Create section without numbering
    \sectiontitleAtrue          % Set the Boolean variable to use the new section title
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}  % Add content to TOC
}
\makeatother
```

And the header of the pages is defined as:

```
\newpagestyle{esitscCD} % Page style of my institution
{
    \esirulehead        % whatever
    \sethead[\numpagpar % If the page is an even number print chapter title
     \;\ chaptertitle ][][]
    {}{}{               % If not print the \sectiontitle or \sectiontitleA depending on ifsectiontitleA
        \ifsectiontitleA \sectiontitleA \else \sectiontitle \fi \numpagodd
}
```

At the end of the special chapter is needed the command `\sectiontitleAfalse` so it keeps printing the `\sectiontitle` of the following chapters. I understand that this is not the optimal solution but I hope it helps someone else. However if you read this post and know a better way to do this please share it, and I hope I am still in time to use it in PhD thesis.